# zend framework get id in /delete/2

Tags: zend-framework, url, param

I'm actually using zend, and I wonder how to get the id in such url :

```
/delete/2
```

I know I can do it using :

```
// if URL is /delete/id/2
$request->getParam('id');
```

But what I want is to have url like the first one `/delete/2` which sounds more logical to me.

Ideas?

Thanks for your help

Comment: ZF as you might know is a conventional MVC, which means you have to send the information in a certain way. Other technique you could use would be Routers, and then this way achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah I know, but it's unfortunately not really a RESTful type of url. Others framework does that job in an easy and elegant way. Anyway, I'm not here to talk about cons & pros of each framework. But just wanted to know if it was possible on Zend. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried Routes mate?

Comment: Yeah I tried but once I put my `addRoute` in my Bootstrap file for example, I've got a missing layout Zend_View

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to solve this kind of problem using routes. You can create a route for

```
/delete/2
```

by adding this to for example your `config.ini` file:

```
[production]
routes.delete.route = "delete/:id"
routes.delete.defaults.controller = delete
routes.delete.defaults.action = index 
routes.delete.id.reqs = "\d+"
```

Here you specify the URL to match, in which words starting with a colon `:` are variables.  As you can see, you can also set requirements on your variables regex-style. In your example, `id` will most likely be one or more digits, resulting in a `\d+` requirement on this variable.

This route will point the url to the `index` action of the `delete` controller and sets `id` as a GET-var. You can alter this .ini code to suit your specific needs.

The routes can be added by putting the following code inside your bootstrap:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/config.ini', 'production');
$router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
$router->addConfig($config, 'routes');
```

See the docs for more information: [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html) for the general documentation and [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.add-config) for the .ini approach I just described.

Comment: in this case we have to add unique entry for each action which passes parameter in url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add the following function to your Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initRoute(){
    $this->bootstrap ('frontcontroller');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $deleteRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'delete/:id',
    array(
        'controller' => '{enter-your-controller-name-here}',
        'action'     => '{enter-your-action-name-here}'
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('delete', $deleteRoute);
}
```

Don't forget to replace {enter-your-controller-name-here} with controller name and {enter-your-action-name-here} with action name.

With this code added, `$request->getParam('id');` should work just fine.